# Using XSLT to transform text with equal sign outside of tag

Tags: xml, xslt, google-search-appliance

I am trying to use XSLT to transform an XML from a GSA (Google search appliance) and getting the following error:

> XmlException: '=' is an unexpected token.  The expected token is ';'.

The XML has the following:

> <NU>
>   /search?q=Testing&site=ActiveCases&lr=&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&output=xml_no_dtd&client=default_frontend&access=p&sort=date:D:L:d1&getfields=%252a&start=10&sa=N
>   </NU>

How do you handle the equal sign outside of the tags?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the equal signs that are causing the problems; it's the ampersands. Try replacing all of your ampersands with `&amp;`.

The reason for the error is that an ampersand starts the beginning of an [entity reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-references). So when the text is parsed, the parser sees the ampersand as the start of the reference. It then expects the entity name ([name characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-NameChar)) and a semicolon to end the reference. The `=` is not a name character and it's not a semicolon, so the error is thrown.

Your other option is to wrap the text in a CDATA section:

```
<NU><![CDATA[/search?q=Testing&site=ActiveCases&lr=&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&output=xml_no_dtd&client=default_frontend&access=p&sort=date:D:L:d1&getfields=%252a&start=10&sa=N]]></NU>
```